# Linking python file into functioning HTML/CSS website

Tags: python, html, css

I'm giving myself a project to better learn these languages which I already know a lot of it's just syncing them together I need to get better with. This project is a pretty basic "SIM" game, generate some animals into your profile with login/logout. So far I've got the website aspect with HTML/CSS done and functioning with all the pages I currently need all of which is local host on my desktop. Now I'm moving on to working with Python and possibly some PHP aspects into this to get the login/logout and generate a new animal into your account.

Everything I've done with python so far has been done in IDEL, I'm wondering how to link my python document to my HTML document. Like you would CSS? Or is that not possible if not then how do I connect the two to have python interact with the HTML/CSS that has been created? I'm guessing to need MySQL for a database setup but seeing how much I can get as a simple local host without hosting online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to setup a localhost with PHP and MYSQL I can recommend XAMP (https://www.apachefriends.org/). In order for your webapp to talk to your Python scripts you will either need to use FLASK or Django to create a python webserver, or use PHP to run python scripts. Either way, you will need to make AJAX requests to an API to get this done.

Edit: Forgot to mention this, but you will need JavaScript in order to do this